# Google map is grey on iOS until I scroll/drag it

Tags: html, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, dynamic-html

I've a Cordova app, where I display the Google map in multiple views.

I am creating the map instance in a div through

```
  mapElement = document.createElement('div');
  mapElement.style.width = '100%';
  mapElement.style.height = '100%';
  mapElement.setAttribute("id", "map");
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
    center: SYDNEY,
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  });
```

I am appending this `mapElement` to parent div element whenever I need to display the map.

It seems to be working on desktop browser, Android, even Safari on mac too. But it doesn't work on iPhone and iOS simulators.

On iPhones & iOS simulators the map appears to be grey as long as I don't touch it, if I drag it a bit, it renders properly.

I've created a minimal solution for my code
**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGGMBq**

**Note**: It seems to be caused by the recent Maps API update I guess, because the same approach was working few days back.

**Here is the script**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<your key here>&libraries=geometry,drawing
```

**What I've tried**

- Triggering resize using google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
- Changing the height of the container using jQuery.
- Few other tweaks

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Did you find a solution please?

Comment: @ZuzuJH This is what solved the problem for me. The problem is that when you don't have the container element available/visible on DOM and initiate the map, then trying to add the container to DOM is not working. So while you initiate the google map, make sure that the container element is available and visible on the map. If you really want to hide it for the user until some action is performed, you can remove it from DOM after the rendering finishes.

Comment: Thank you Raj. I will definitely give that a try.

Answer (score -1):

You must declare ahead of time access to private data. Private data includes camera, location, calender, photos,microphone and so forth. You do this by adding a usage key in the  app's Info.plist together with a purpose string.So this is what you need to do:

After adding the Geolocation plugin, you need to add the following in your config.xml file. This will then be compiled  in the app's Info.plist:

```
<config-file  parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" 
target="*-Info.plist">

    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>

<config-file>
```

Lastly you will have to remove the platform and add it again. You can do this using this command:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```